# TransactionProxyException is thrown while creating a BizTalk Group

Tags: sql-server, biztalk

I'm trying to create a BizTalk Group on BizTalk Server 2013 using this documentation:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248696%28v=bts.80%29.aspx

But it fails on creating group (It succeeds creating SSODB).

The error in the log file is:

> [Group] Failed to configure with error message [Exception of type 'System.EnterpriseServices.TransactionProxyException' was thrown.]

For additional information: While it's doing the configuration I watched the Database Server and saw that It created the 3 databases successfully (BizTalkMgmtDb, BizTalkMsgBoxDb, BizTalkDTADb) but after it fails for some reason it rollbacks and deletes the created database.

Something to notice is that while rolling back the changes, all created databases are deleted expect `BizTalkMgmtDb` which fails to drop.

There's also this lines in the log before it starts to roll back:

```
2014-04-22 12:24:10:0729 [INFO] WMI Deploying 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013\Microsoft.BizTalk.GlobalPropertySchemas.dll'

2014-04-22 12:24:14:0563 [WARN] AdminLib GetBTSMessage: hrErr=80070002; Msg=The system cannot find the file specified.; 

2014-04-22 12:24:14:0565 [WARN] AdminLib GetBTSMessage: hrErr=c0c02560; Msg=Failed to read "KeepDbDebugKey" from the registry.
The system cannot find the file specified.; 

2014-04-22 12:24:14:0566 [INFO] WMI Error occurred during database creation; attempt to rollback and delete the partially created database'sql-srv\BizTalkMsgBoxDb'
```

**Question:** What this exception is about and how can I resolve it?

FYI: I'm using BizTalk Server 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully, you just need to correct you MSDTC settings.

This article at TechNet has all the details:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6917.biztalk-server-2010-msdtc.aspx

BizTalk Server 2013 and 2010 are identical in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your BizTalk Server is not properly installed.

Please try the following steps:

1. Repair the BizTalk Server installation
2. Go to SQL Server Management Studio and delete remaining BizTalk databases including SSO database
3. Configure the BizTalk
4. Create BizTalk Group